# JTable template error

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to use instead any jTable my own tabletemplate which takes own abstartc model but in my constructor i get always some errors.What can be wrong here?

```
public class TableTemplate extends JTable {
    private AbstractTableModel tableModel;
    public TableTemplate(  Class <? extends AbstractTableModel> a) {
        super();
        tableModel=a;
        this.setModel(a);
    }
...
}
```

EDIT:
it shoudl work for:

```
TableTemplate(carTableAbstractModel) //extedns AbstarctTableMode l
TableTemplate(personTableAbstractModel) //extedns AbstarctTableModel
```

Comment: what's an error? post a SSCCE, please.

Comment: Your constructor declaration is wrong. You do not need a `Class` instance, but an `AbstractTableModel` instance. Replace it with `public TableTemplate(AbstractTableModel a)`

Comment: but it ll work when i am using for abstarcttablemodel othere template  classes? i added in "EDIT" code.

Comment: A house and the plan of a house are not the same thing. The constructor expects an Class<? extends AbstractTableModel> (the plan of a house, in my analogy), and tries to assign it to a variable of type AbstractTableModel (a house, in my analogy). As Robin has already told you, the constructor must take an AbstractTableModel as argument. Not a Class.

Comment: I wanted to add/delete rows throw the jtable, so i needed there CarTableAbsrtactModel instead AbstractModel because in CarTableAbstractModel i have iplemented thoose functions addRow/deleteRow. Thats why i needthere my own AbstractModel